# Backbone event Aggregator -notify when all event handler are done processing

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

In our project we have a event agree-gator used to save the data.We have many views who listen to the save and do there work. its all independent.
Now what we want to do is have a mechanism to know that all views are done with the save.

Basically meaning find out if all event subscribers are done with there work.

Do you guys know of a pattern which we can sue or do we need to redesign save infrastructure.

Answer (score 1):

Seems not dissimilar from what jQuery Deferreds allow you to do:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/

Comment: an example of the deferred mechanism can be seen here: https://github.com/marionettejs/bbclonemail/blob/master/public/javascripts/bbclonemail/mail/mailbox/mail.js#L30-L37

Comment: and this is interesting too: http://davidsulc.com/blog/2013/04/01/using-jquery-promises-to-render-backbone-views-after-fetching-data/